# Can neural network actually learn?

Tags: neural-network, simulation, genetic-algorithm

I'm creating an evolution-artificial-life-simulation game in 2D (purely for fun purposes). It combines neural networks (for behaviour controlling) and genetic algorithm (for breeding and mutations).

On input I give them X,Y position of nearest food (normalized) and X,Y position of the "look at" vector.

Currently they fly around and when they collide with food (let's call it "eating apples") their fitness index is increased by one and the apple's position is randomed - after 2000 turns the GA interrupts and does its magic.
After about 100 generations they learn that eating apples is good and try to fly to the nearest ones.

But my question, as a neural network newbie, is - if I created a room where apples spawn way more frequent than on the rest of the map, would they learn and understand that? Would they fly to that room more often? And is it possible to tell how many generations would it take for them to learn?

Comment: In theory - yes, but this really depends on how you "allow" them to learn. [Unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning)

Answer (score 1):

What they can learn and how fast depends a lot on the information you give them access to. For instance, if they have no way of knowing that they are in the room where food generates more frequently, then there is no way for them to evolve to go there more frequently.

It's not entirely clear from your question what the "look at" vector is. If it, for instance, shows them what's directly in front of them, then it might be enough information for them to figure out that they're in the room of plenty, particularly if that room "looks" distinctive somehow. A more useful input to give them might be their current X and Y coordinates. If you did that, then I would definitely expect them to evolve to be in the good room more frequently (in proportion to how good it is, of course), because it would be possible for them to take action to go to and stay in that room.

As for how many generations it will take, that is incredibly hard to predict (especially without knowing more about your setup). If it takes them 100 generations to learn to eat food, then I would expect it to be on the order of hundreds. But the best way to find out is just to try it.

Comment: The "look at" vector is the direction vector (normalized), but I'm on my way to implementing their "eyes" so they could learn to recognize what's in front of them. I should give them coordinates as a propotion to whole map's size, I presume?

Comment: Ah, okay. That might or might not be enough for them to go on. If you're going to give them their coordinates, the easiest thing to do is probably to give them in whatever units you give the coordinates of the nearest food in.

Answer (score 1):

If it's all about location, they may keep a state of the map in their mind and simple statistics will let them learn where the food may be located. Neural nets is an overkill there.

If there are other features of locations (for example color, smell, height etc...) to map those features to the label (food exists or not) is good for neural nets. Especially if some of features not available or not reliable randomly at the moment.

If they need many decisions to reach the goal, you will need reinforcement learning. Forexample, they may go to a direction which is good for a time, but make them away from resources they will need later.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I understand. The color and smell ideas are really cool, I handn't thought before about this (I only thought about color as for their color and food's).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a recurrent neural network could learn to expect apples to spawn in a certain region.